Cloud Foundry Java Client in Springboot: login through /oauth/token fails
I have a spring boot project which interacts with Cloud Foundry
I have the following code:
CloudFoundryController.java:
package com.backend

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationFailedEvent;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;

import org.cloudfoundry.operations.CloudFoundryOperations;
import org.cloudfoundry.operations.applications.GetApplicationRequest;
import org.cloudfoundry.operations.DefaultCloudFoundryOperations;
import org.cloudfoundry.reactor.DefaultConnectionContext;
import org.cloudfoundry.reactor.TokenProvider;
import org.cloudfoundry.reactor.client.ReactorCloudFoundryClient;
import org.cloudfoundry.reactor.tokenprovider.PasswordGrantTokenProvider;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class BackendApplication implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationFailedEvent> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BackendApplication.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Hardcoded Cloud Foundry client configuration
        String target = "thisistheurl";
        String org = "thisisthename";
        String space = "thisisthename";
        String user = "thisisthelogin";
        String password = "thisisthepass";

        try {
// Configure and login to Cloud Foundry
            final PasswordGrantTokenProvider tokenProvider = PasswordGrantTokenProvider.builder()
                    .username(user)
                    .password(password)
                    .build();

            final DefaultConnectionContext connectionContext = DefaultConnectionContext.builder()
                    .apiHost(target)
                    .build();

            final ReactorCloudFoundryClient client = ReactorCloudFoundryClient.builder()
                    .connectionContext(connectionContext)
                    .tokenProvider(tokenProvider)
                    .build();

            final DefaultCloudFoundryOperations operations = DefaultCloudFoundryOperations.builder()
                    .cloudFoundryClient(client)
                    .organization(org)
                    .space(space)
                    .build();

            operations.applications().list().subscribe(application ->
                    System.out.printf("  %s%n", application.getName())
            );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error interacting with Cloud Foundry: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    private static URL getTargetURL(String target) {
        try {
            return URI.create(target).toURL();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The target URL is not valid: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


I have the following libraries:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudfoundry-operations</artifactId>
            <version>5.12.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudfoundry-client-reactor</artifactId>
            <version>5.12.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

What i get is:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
And corresponding exception:
2024-04-21T23:26:04.769+12:00 ERROR 36848 --- [backend] [ry-client-nio-2] cloudfoundry-client.compatibility        : An error occurred while checking version compatibility:

org.cloudfoundry.uaa.UaaException: invalid_client: Bad credentials
    at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.ErrorPayloadMappers.lambda$null$8(ErrorPayloadMappers.java:104) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-5.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.checkpoint(Mono.java:2261)
    org.cloudfoundry.reactor.tokenprovider.AbstractUaaTokenProvider.token(AbstractUaaTokenProvider.java:330)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint() ⇢ at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.tokenprovider.AbstractUaaTokenProvider.token(AbstractUaaTokenProvider.java:330)
    *__checkpoint() ⇢ at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.client.v2.info.ReactorInfo.get(ReactorInfo.java:52)

when I perform the following operation:
cf -a thisistheurl -u thisisthelogin -p thisisthepass

it works perfectly, login is working.
However from what i see, the java library does the following:

makes a GET request to api url provided and obtains cloud_controller_v2 property as new link
makes a GET request to newlink/v2/info and obtains authorization_endpoint, which is something like login.thisistheurl
tries to make POST to login.thisistheurl/oauth/token and gets 'unauthorized' which is completely true, as I can't login with my creds through browser (and probably should not be able to.

Can anybody help with corrections in my implementation?

First, please expand on what you mean by "can't login through browser". Do you have user creds? or client credentials? Second, what is the specific cf command you're running? login or auth? When you run your cf command like cf login set CF_TRACE=true before your run it. That will show you the HTTP requests it's making. Then use step 5.) at this link https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client?tab=readme-ov-file#troubleshooting to do the same with your Java app and compare the two.

Hey Daniel! Thank you for your answer!
When I was writing this under "I can't login through browser" meant navigating to login.thisistheurl/oauth/token will request login and password and when I use the ones that i am using in the command cf -a thisistheurl -u thisisthelogin -p thisisthepass, the credential are rejected.
It seems like the issue disappered for me. Spending some time on understanding why, I found that my code works perfectly. I didn't find the reason.

The code actually works perfect. I had to check the accuracy in handling the variables. Exact issue is unknow.
